# Delete attachments ramification

Tags: attachment

We have 1.6 gig of attachments. If the client doesn't need the anymore and I just remove them via dataloader from the attachment object, does it break any standard SF functionality? Anything one needs to look out for?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you just deleted the record which your client doesn't need. It won't break anything.

Unless you didn't deleted any important files which your client might need.

And if your query attachment in code then you might don't get any result. You might need to handle that but its hard to tell without scanning complete code.